# resteasy-multipart-provider, Maven, Java, MultipartFormDataInput. Empty uploaded pdf file

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy

I've the following problem. In my pom file I updated my dependency to:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and now, when I'm trying to upload pdf file, the file comes up empty. If I use the `<version>2.3.2.Final</version>` everything is ok, but there is problem with the UTF-8 symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. So I had updated to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and now everything works fine :)